# What is the fastest method(s) for reading and writing a matrix of Float64 to file in julia

Tags: julia

Let `x = randn(100, 2)`. I want to write `x` to its own file. This file will contain `x`, and only `x`, and `x` will only ever be of type `Matrix{Float64}`. In the past, I have always used `HDF5` for this, but it occurs to me that this is over-kill, since in this setup I will only have one array per file. Note that `JLD` uses `HDF5`, and so is also over-kill.

**1)** What is the fastest method for reading and writing `x` assuming I will only ever want to read the entire matrix?

**2)** What is the fastest method for reading and writing `x` assuming I might want to read a slice of the matrix?

**3)** What is the fastest method for reading and writing `x` assuming I might want to read a slice of the matrix, or over-write a slice of the matrix (but *not* change the matrix size)?

Comment: If `x` is not too big, memory mapping sounds efficient and very simple to manage (using `Mmap.mmap`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `serialize` function, provided you heed the warnings in the documentation about non-guarantees between versions etc.

> serialize(stream::IO, value)
>
> Write an arbitrary value to a stream in an opaque format, such that it can be read back by deserialize. The read-back value will be as identical as possible to the original. In general, this process will not work if the reading and writing are done by different
>     versions of Julia, or an instance of Julia with a different system image. Ptr values are serialized as all-zero bit patterns (NULL).
>
> An 8-byte identifying header is written to the stream first. To avoid writing the header, construct a SerializationState and use it as the first argument to serialize instead. See also Serializer.writeheader.

Really though, JLD (or in fact, its successor, [JLD2](https://github.com/simonster/JLD2.jl)) is generally the recommended way*.

---

<sub>*Of particular interest to you might be the statements that: **"JLD2 saves and loads Julia data structures in a format comprising a subset of HDF5, without any dependency on the HDF5 C library"** and that **"it typically outperforms the previous JLD package (sometimes by multiple orders of magnitude) and often outperforms Julia's built-in serializer"**.</sub>

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of `serialize`, but the version and system image restriction is too much for the application I have in mind unfortunately. But I was not aware that `JLD2` will not depend on the `HDF5` C library. That is very cool - I will look into it.

Comment: Huh. Just put together a simple write test for `JLD2` and it comes out over an order of magnitude slower than `serialize` and twice as slow as `writedlm`. I've asked a question about it on discourse [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/jld2-seems-really-slow-at-write-operations-compared-to-serialize-hdf5-and-writedlm/7177)

Comment: Oops, error in my test. After correcting for the error, it is still 4 times slower than `HDF5` alas...

Comment: Mind you, all these libraries have tiny overheads, which for your specific test and use case tend to accumulate. If your matrix is always float then you could probably just create your own binary read / write function which accesses elements based on file pointer position (particularly if the size of the matrix, or at least the number of columns, is also always the same).

Comment: Funnily enough, I was playing around with exactly that option last night and I think that you are right. I'll do a bit more messing around today and will post an answer here if I find anything interesting. Thanks for your responses, they were helpful. Based on what I've read, it sounds like `JLD2` will ultimately be the right solution, once the devs have had a chance implement optimisation tweaks - my understanding is that Simon's concurrently finishing a PhD, so probably doesn't have a whole lot of spare time for free dev work :-)

Comment: Did some rudimentary tests of 4 different methods and wrote the results up in an answer below. In short, writing binaries is the preferred method at this point. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the suggestions made by Tasos above, I put together a rudimentary speed test for both writes and reads using 4 different methods:

1. h5 (using the HDF5 package)
2. jld (using the JLD2 package)
3. slz (using `serialize` and `deserialize`)
4. dat (write to a binary file, using the first 128 bits to store the dimension of the matrix)

I've pasted the test code at the bottom of this answer. The results are:

```
julia> @time f_write_test(N, "h5")
  0.191555 seconds (2.11 k allocations: 76.380 MiB, 26.39% gc time)

julia> @time f_write_test(N, "jld")
  0.774857 seconds (8.33 k allocations: 77.058 MiB, 0.32% gc time)

julia> @time f_write_test(N, "slz")
  0.108687 seconds (2.61 k allocations: 76.495 MiB, 1.91% gc time)

julia> @time f_write_test(N, "dat")
  0.087488 seconds (1.61 k allocations: 76.379 MiB, 1.08% gc time)

julia> @time f_read_test(N, "h5")
  0.051646 seconds (5.81 k allocations: 76.515 MiB, 14.80% gc time)

julia> @time f_read_test(N, "jld")
  0.071249 seconds (10.04 k allocations: 77.136 MiB, 57.60% gc time)

julia> @time f_read_test(N, "slz")
  0.038967 seconds (3.11 k allocations: 76.527 MiB, 22.17% gc time)

julia> @time f_read_test(N, "dat")
  0.068544 seconds (1.81 k allocations: 76.405 MiB, 59.21% gc time)
```

So for writes, the write to binary option outperforms even `serialize`, and is twice as fast as `HDF5` and almost an order of magnitude faster than `JLD2`.

For reads, `deserialize` has the best performance, while `HDF5`, `JLD2` and reading from binary are all fairly close in performance, with `HDF5` being slightly ahead.

I haven't included a test for writing to slices, but may come back to this in the future. Obviously writing to slices is impossible using `serialize` (not to mention the versioning/system image issues that `serialize` also faces), and I'm not really sure how to do it using `JLD2`. My gut feel writing a slice to binary will easily beat `HDF5` if the slice is contiguous on disk, but will probably be significantly slower than `HDF5` if it is non-contiguous *and* if the `HDF5` method optimally exploits chunking. If `HDF5` doesn't exploit chunking (which implies knowing at write time what slices you will want), then I suspect the binary method will come out ahead.

In summary, I'm going to go with the binary method, as I think that at this stage it is clearly the overall winner.

I suspect that eventually, `JLD2` will probably be the method of choice, but there is a fair way to go here (the package itself is very new so not much time for the community to work on optimisations etc).

Test code follows:

```
using JLD2, HDF5
f_write_h5(fp::String, x::Matrix{Float64}) = h5write(fp, "G/D", x)
f_write_jld(fp::String, x::Matrix{Float64}) = @save fp x
f_write_slz(fp::String, x::Matrix{Float64}) = open(fid->serialize(fid, x), fp, "w")
f_write_dat_inner(fid1::IOStream, x::Matrix{Float64}) = begin ; write(fid1, size(x,1)) ; write(fid1, size(x,2)) ; write(fid1, x) ; end
f_write_dat(fp::String, x::Matrix{Float64}) = open(fid1->f_write_dat_inner(fid1, x), fp, "w")
f_read_h5(fp::String) = h5read(fp, "G/D")
f_read_jld(fp::String) = @load fp x
f_read_slz(fp::String) = open(deserialize, fp, "r")
f_read_dat_inner(fid1::IOStream) = begin ; d1 = read(fid1, Int) ; d2 = read(fid1, Int) ; read(fid1, Float64, (d1, d2)) ; end
f_read_dat(fp::String) = open(f_read_dat_inner, fp, "r")
function f_write_test(N::Int, filetype::String)
    dp = "/home/colin/Temp/"
    filetype == "h5" && [ f_write_h5("$(dp)$(n).$(filetype)", randn(1000, 100)) for n = 1:N ]
    filetype == "jld" && [ f_write_jld("$(dp)$(n).$(filetype)", randn(1000, 100)) for n = 1:N ]
    filetype == "slz" && [ f_write_slz("$(dp)$(n).$(filetype)", randn(1000, 100)) for n = 1:N ]
    filetype == "dat" && [ f_write_dat("$(dp)$(n).$(filetype)", randn(1000, 100)) for n = 1:N ]
    #[ rm("$(dp)$(n).$(filetype)") for n = 1:N ]
    nothing
end
function f_read_test(N::Int, filetype::String)
    dp = "/home/colin/Temp/"
    filetype == "h5" && [ f_read_h5("$(dp)$(n).$(filetype)") for n = 1:N ]
    filetype == "jld" && [ f_read_jld("$(dp)$(n).$(filetype)") for n = 1:N ]
    filetype == "slz" && [ f_read_slz("$(dp)$(n).$(filetype)") for n = 1:N ]
    filetype == "dat" && [ f_read_dat("$(dp)$(n).$(filetype)") for n = 1:N ]
    [ rm("$(dp)$(n).$(filetype)") for n = 1:N ]
    nothing
end
f_write_test(1, "h5")
f_write_test(1, "jld")
f_write_test(1, "slz")
f_write_test(1, "dat")
f_read_test(1, "h5")
f_read_test(1, "jld")
f_read_test(1, "slz")
f_read_test(1, "dat")

N = 100
@time f_write_test(N, "h5")
@time f_write_test(N, "jld")
@time f_write_test(N, "slz")
@time f_write_test(N, "dat")
@time f_read_test(N, "h5")
@time f_read_test(N, "jld")
@time f_read_test(N, "slz")
@time f_read_test(N, "dat")
```

Answer (score 1):

Julia has two build-in functions [`readdlm`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/delimitedfiles/#DelimitedFiles.readdlm-Tuple%7BAny,Char,Type,Char%7D) & [`writedlm`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/delimitedfiles/#DelimitedFiles.writedlm) for doing this:

```
julia> x = randn(5, 5)
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 -1.2837    -0.641382  0.611415   0.965762   -0.962764 
  0.106015  -0.344429  1.40278    0.862094    0.324521 
 -0.603751   0.515505  0.381738  -0.167933   -0.171438 
 -1.79919   -0.224585  1.05507   -0.753046    0.0545622
 -0.110378  -1.16155   0.774612  -0.0796534  -0.503871 

julia> writedlm("txtmat.txt", x, use_mmap=true)

julia> readdlm("txtmat.txt", use_mmap=true)
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 -1.2837    -0.641382  0.611415   0.965762   -0.962764 
  0.106015  -0.344429  1.40278    0.862094    0.324521 
 -0.603751   0.515505  0.381738  -0.167933   -0.171438 
 -1.79919   -0.224585  1.05507   -0.753046    0.0545622
 -0.110378  -1.16155   0.774612  -0.0796534  -0.503871
```

Definitely not the fastest way(use `Mmap.mmap` directly as DanGetz suggested in the comment if performance is a big deal), but it seems this is the simplest way and the output file is human-readable.

Comment: But `readdlm` and `writedlm` are 1 to 2 orders of magnitude slower then `HDF5`...