# How to write/read array of strings to .bin with good performance

Tags: julia, binaryfiles

Writing an array of strings to .bin format is done as follows

```
out =  open("string_array.bin","w")
a = ["first string","second string","third string"]
write(out,a)
close(out)
```

But when it comes to reading back array a, things start to get tricky.

```
out =  open("string_array.bin","r")
a = read(out)
close(out)
typeof(a) # returns Array{UInt8,1}
```

How does one convert the Array{UInt8,1} back to the original a array of type Array{String,1}?

It needs to also work when the array of strings has 300+ million elements, i.e. the solution has to be well performing.

Comment: Your code above will not work as `write(out, a)` will fail, because `a` contains a string and writing such structures (not-isbits) to a stream is not supported. This comment is for Julia 1.0. On Julia 0.6 it works but it just concatenates strings in the output so it is impossible to parse back their original values.

Comment: Your comment on Julia 0.6 is exactly correct.

Comment: In Julia 0.6 it should be safe to use JLD2.jl as the problems with JLD2.jl noted below are related to porting it to Julia 1.0. Also other options listed below will work.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Out of curiosity, on v0.7+, how bad an idea would it be to use `unsafe_wrap` to convert a `String` to `Vector{UInt8}`, write the `Vector{UInt8}` to a binary file, then you can read the `Vector{UInt8}` back from the file, and convert it to `String`? If you have a `Vector{String}` then you could just do this in sequence and use an additional `UInt8` to store the length of each `Vector{UInt8}`. (or a bigger integer type if the strings are really long). Is this a terrible idea? (it would probably only be 5 or 6 lines of code)

Comment: @Mr_Holm Also, I conducted a similar exercise for `Matrix{Float64}` and found that writing to and reading from a binary file was the overall best solution (currently). It's all in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343845/what-is-the-fastest-methods-for-reading-and-writing-a-matrix-of-float64-to-fil)

Comment: This is perfectly OK to do and you do not need to do `unsafe_wrap` but use `codeunits` that is designed exactly to give access to bytes of a string (and is safe). I was also thinking of this, but I thought that this is too hacky. I think you could add it as an alternative answer :).

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński I did it. You're right, it is a bit hacky  :-)  But it should be fast, especially for longer strings. I suspect performance should be reasonably close to `serialize`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Bogumil is right, it is a bit hacky, but if you are keen to write and read to binary files, then here is an implementation for reading and writing `Vector{String}` that works by converting each `String` to `Vector{UInt8}`, then writing each `Vector{UInt8}` to file, using an initial `Int64` for each `Vector{UInt8}` to store its length. The file also starts with an extra `Int64` that stores the length of the `Vector{String}`. The read routines then use this information to pull it all back in and convert it back to `Vector{String}`:

```
my_write(fid1::IOStream, x::Vector{UInt8}) = begin ; write(fid1, Int64(length(x))) ; write(fid1, x) ; end
my_write(fid1::IOStream, x::Vector{Vector{UInt8}}) = begin ; write(fid1, Int64(length(x))) ; [ my_write(fid1, y) for y in x ] ; end
my_read(fid1::IOStream, ::Type{Vector{UInt8}})::Vector{UInt8} = begin i = read(fid1, Int64) ; [ read(fid1, UInt8) for a = 1:i ] ; end
my_read(fid1::IOStream, ::Type{Vector{Vector{UInt8}}})::Vector{Vector{UInt8}} = begin i = read(fid1, Int64) ; [ my_read(fid1, Vector{UInt8}) for a = 1:i ] ; end
my_write(myfilepath::String, x::Vector{String}) = open(fid1 -> my_write(fid1, [ Vector{UInt8}(codeunits(y)) for y in x ]), myfilepath, "w")
function my_read(myfilepath::String, ::Type{Vector{String}})::Vector{String}
    x = open(fid1 -> my_read(fid1, Vector{Vector{UInt8}}), myfilepath, "r")
    return [ String(y) for y in x ]
end
```

I've probably included a little more type information than is necessary, but it might make things a bit more obvious to you. Also, sorry, I have a bad habit of doing this sort of thing with one-liners, but you can easily unpack it if necessary. Here's some test code (just adjust the filepath):

```
myfilepath = "/home/colin/Temp/test_file.bin"
x = ["abc", "de", "f", "", "ghij"]
my_write(myfilepath, x)
my_read(myfilepath, Vector{String})
```

Note, with a little bit of effort, this code can be made more general so that it will work for pretty much any `Vector{Vector{T}}` as long as `T` is writable. In fact, if you're really clever, it should be able to be generalized to any `Vector{Vector{Vector{...{T}}}}`, as long as you can get the recursion right.

Comment: Nice! As a side remark I like to use `foreach` instead of comprehensions if I do need to store the result of a function.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `foreach`. In my own code if I don't need the result, I often just use `for blah ; do something  ; end`, but `foreach` is much neater. In this case, I'm tempted to leave the comprehension because it will result in the final output being a `Vector{Int}` with the length of each `String` that was written, which is not an entirely useless output to get (although admittedly I can't think of an application off the top of my head).

Comment: Great answer @ColinTBowers! Your solution gets the job done, only way to top this would be to write to binary using all available workers in the session. Could one do this using pmap, or is a custom @spawn/remove_fetch the way to go?

Comment: @Mr_Holm Honestly I've never had a need to parallel or thread stuff in Julia before so I am definitely the wrong person to ask. Having said that, i think most of the runtime in the routine will be on the actual read and write of UInt8 to file, rather than the conversions, and that has to be done sequentially, so I can't see how pmap would help there. But you could definitely pmap the conversions easily enough.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

- [serialization](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/Serialization/#Serialization-1), its limitation is that it was designed for short term storage (it requires that Julia reading and writing the file has the same system image).
- [JLD2.jl](https://github.com/simonster/JLD2.jl), the caveat is that as of writing there are some unresolved issues with the package on Julia 1.0 (those should be fixed soon - you can check out issues if they affect you - the major thing is handling of `missing`; given what you write you should not be affected by them)
- finally you can use readers/writers designed to handle tabular data, like [CSV.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl) or [Feather.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/Feather.jl), as your data can be considered as a single-column table

Comment: Thanks Bogumil! These are all great options if your data is not in the 300+ million elements range. For smaller data size Feather.jl would be a fast option. I expect writing to binary would beat Feather anytime. But how does one go about doing that?

Comment: Have you tried actually testing them? I have just tested that `serialize` takes ~10 seconds saving 100,000,000 strings of size 10 characters each on a laptop, so I guess this should be fast enough for most use cases.

Comment: Yes, but will that process work if the reading and writing are done by different versions of Julia?

Comment: Not guaranteed. That is why I have listed different options and I have given their most important limitations as I do not know what you need exactly. The more general solution is the slower it can be expected to be as a rule of thumb. Given what you specified JLD2.jl could strike a good balance for you.

Comment: Just for your reference I have just checked that writing such an array (100 million rows) as CSV using `writedlm` from `DelimitedFiles` standard library takes ~23 seconds which is not that bad either.